# Google Sheet (Query, Indirect) enhancement

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I am using formula

```
=QUERY({INDIRECT(H10);INDIRECT(H11)},"select * where B is not null")
```

in Google sheets, and is giving me a perfect output.

```
Col1  |  Col2

Apple |  100

Banana|   50
```

But I need to get a sheet name as well with the output to know which sheet the value belongs to.

E.g. below:

```
Col1   | Col2   |  Col3

Sheet1 | Apple  |  100

Sheet2 | Banana |  50
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: It's not possible to get the Sheet Name with Formulas, but you can do it with Apps Script. Would this fit your needs?